# Does EF Core provide a way to map a get-only property to database

Tags: ef-core-2.1

I have a client object that has a computed value `Fullname` that I want stored to the database but don't want/need it returned from the database because it is computed from other fields.

```
public class Client
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Firstname {get; set;}
   public string Middlename {get; set;}
   public string Lastname {get; set;}

   public string Fullname => this.FormatName(NameFormats.LastFirst);
}
```

In this case, I want it in the database so reporting users can use the fullname for printing/listing without having to compute it.  But I don't need it brought back into my domain model because it's always computed from `Firstname` and `Lastname` which are already being brought in from the database.

**Is it possible to define a "store to database only" property on an Entity with EF Core?**

Comment: There isn't. But you can add feature request for that [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=label:type-enhancement+) :)

Comment: Thanks, I added the request: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13316

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution from the EF Core team [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13316#issuecomment-421052406) was as follows:

> We discussed this in #7946 and decided that having an empty setter is reasonable for this scenario. For example:

```
public string Fullname
{
    get => $"{this.Lastname}, {this.Firstname}";
    private set { }
}
```

Comment: This looks very hacky. I hope they improve this at some point. Thanks a lot though, fixed my problem as well.